# Solution to find an element in a list with a for loop

Tags: python, list

A question regarding finding an element in a list.

```
list1 = ['One', 'two', 'three']

def check(list1, inp):
    for i in list1:
        if(i == inp):
            print ("Exist!")
        else: 
            print('No')

check(list1, 'One)
```

The above code returns:
Exist!
No
No

I would like to write a code that returns only 'Exist' if an element is in the list. Or 'No', one time, if the element is not in the list. Has anybody a solution for that while still use a for loop?

Comment: Skip the loop and use `if inp in list1:`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Building one your loopy approach, you can do the following:

```
def check(list1, inp):
    for i in list1:
        if i == inp:
            print("Exist!")
            return  # ends the function!
    print("No")
```

As you can see, you only print `"No"` once you iterated the entire list. Of course, there are better membership tests:

```
def check(list1, inp):
    if inp in list1:
        print("Exist!")
    else:
        print("No")
```

Or if the test for the elements is some more complex condition other than simple equality, you can still use `any` to implement this short-circuiting pattern:

```
def check(list1, inp):
    if any(condition(i, inp) for i in list1):
        print("Exist!")
    else:
        print("No")
```